# Flutter : How to call a screen onclick on image of reusable appbar

Tags: image, flutter, appbar

I have created a reusable appBar class and calling it wherever i want to use
here is the code

```
class MyAppBar extends AppBar {
  
 MyAppBar({Key key,Widget title})
   :super(key:key ,title:title,actions: <Widget>[
     InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Profile();
            
        },
        child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
            child: ClipOval(
            
                child: Image.network(
                    'https://googleflutter.com/sample_image.jpg',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
  
   ]
   );}
```

when click on image it is not redirecting to profile screen.
i used this also

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Profile()));
```

but it's giving me error on context as it's not define.

please help if anyone know how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried notifying parent class? You can pass a function to appbar class and then when tapped, it will call the function on the parent class. This function navigate to other page.  You can also have a look navigating without context article https://medium.com/flutter-community/navigate-without-context-in-flutter-with-a-navigation-service-e6d76e880c1c If any of these is helpful please notify me

Comment: Could please edit my code with your answer? i am not getting how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can have the access of `context` inside a build function so do it like this,
create a function variable inside you custom appbar and give it to InkWell like this,

```
class MyAppBar extends AppBar {
final Function onPressed;
...

InkWell(
onTap: onPressed,
child:...
   )
 }
```

now where you use the appbar pass that function there like this,

```
Scaffold(
appBar : MyAppBar(
onPressed: (){
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Profile()));
   },
title: ...
 ),
);
```